# Azure Data Factory : Dynamic incremental load Salesforce data to Azure SQL Database

Tags: salesforce, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am looking for documentation for weeks, I would like to know if you know some documentation about Incremental load between Salesforce Database to Azure SQL Database

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also searched and find nothing. Data Factory documents don't tell us which source support the Incremental load. I think you could add a new [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) here, Azure Data Factory product team may see it and give you the answer.

Comment: Hi @hugo, may I post it as answer?

Comment: Hi, yes there is nothing about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also searched and find nothing. Data Factory documents don't tell us which source support the Incremental load.

I think you could add a new [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) here, Azure Data Factory product team may see it and give you the answer.